# How to memset an array of bools?

Tags: c++

```
void *memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count)
```

The 3rd argument is the Number of characters or bytes in the array.
How would you memset an array of booleans, say bool bArray[11]?

MSDN says: "Security Note - Make sure that the destination buffer has enough room for at least count characters."

Comment: `bool bArray[11] = {}`? Or `std::fill(begin(bArray), end(bArray), true)`?

Comment: `11 * sizeof(bool)`. That being said, that's not very c++; you should be using `std::fill()`

Comment: Seems vector<bool> is optimized for space allocation and is a 'real' array of bits. A C++ style array of bools is essentially an array of bytes with all bits either 0 or 1.

Vector<bool> is the way to go. Thanks for all the responses. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user173438: `vector<bool>` is slow.  You probably wanted `std::bitset`.

Comment: @user173438: `vector<bool>` is also (surprisingly) not a normal container, unlike `vector`. See explanation here:
http://books.google.de/books?id=_1uD7khOQooC&lpg=PA42&vq=vector%3Cbool%3E&hl=de&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: From the Standard *"Using a `bool` value in ways described by this International Standard as “undefined,” such as by examining the value of an uninitialized automatic object, might cause it to behave as if it is neither `true` nor `false`."*   `memset`-ing the memory a `bool` use certainly falls into this undefined category.

Answer (score 20):

`std::fill()` should use `memset()` when possible.

```
std::fill(std::begin(bArray), std::end(bArray), value);
```

If `bArray` is a pointer, then the following should be used:

```
std::fill(bArray, bArray + arraySize, value);
```

Comment: If he gets bArray via a pointer, how can you get `std::end(bArray)`?

Comment: @einpoklum If `bArray` is a pointer, this line should be `std::fill(bArray, bArray + arraySize, value);`

Comment: @MewX: Obviously, but that's not what this answer says right now.

Answer (score 5):

```
memset(buffer_start, value, sizeof(bool) * number_of_bools);
```

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` makes little sense there - memset just fills each byte with a bool.

Comment: @blaisorblade Yes sizeof(bool) == 1, but clearly stating your intent in code is never a bad thing.

Comment: Size of bool may not be 1.

Comment: Elaborating on what Neil said, as per 5.3.3/1: "sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is _implementation-defined._ [ **Note: in particular, sizeof(bool)**, sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined."

Answer (score 3):

```
//Array declaration
bool arr[10];

//To initialize all the elements to true

memset(arr,1,sizeof(arr));
```

Similarly, you can initialize all the elements to false, by replacing 1 with 0.

Answer (score 0):

memset sets memory in multiples of bytes. So, the only way is to add padding to your bool pointer such that its length is a multiple of 8. Then do memset.
Personally I would prefer if there were any other alternative than putting a redundant padding. But I haven't found any alternative solution to date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this example:

```
    bool primes[MAX];
    memset(primes,true,sizeof(bool) * MAX);
```

Answer (score -1):

To set array of 11 bool elements to e.g. true by using `memset`:

```
const int N = 11;
bool arr[N];
memset(arr, 1, sizeof(bool) * N);
```

Comment: It should be memset(arr, 1, sizeof(bool) * N);