# What's the best way to initialize a dynamically allocated boolean 2d array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Just trying to (re)learn C and struggling with some basic concepts.

I've took a look this thread: [How to memset an array of bools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215210/how-to-memset-an-array-of-bools).

According to that, it seems i may initialize a boolean 2d array like the following:

```
size_t size = sizeof(bool[4][3]);
bool (*ary)[4] = malloc(size);
memset(ary, false, size);
```

The problem i see with this code is that it depends on a boolean taking 1 byte, which i think is implementation dependant. Apart from that, the second parameter to memset according to my manual page (linux manpages project) seems to be an int... That manual page says "The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c". Isn't this contradictory? If c is an int then it's not a byte long.

**EDIT1**: See Ouroborus comment below about the last paragraph.

So after thinking a bit, i came up with the following code:

```
size_t size = sizeof(bool[4][3]);
bool (*ary)[4] = malloc(size);
const bool orig[4][3] = {
    {true, false, false},
    {false, true, true},
    {true, true, true},
    {false, false, false}
};
memcpy(ary, &orig, size);
```

This way i can initialize my memory not just with 0s (false), but with whatever i want. I've tested and this doesn't work at all.

So my question is: What's wrong with my code? And more important, what's the way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "...with the constant byte c." So `c` is a byte, not an int.

Comment: yeah, but the same manpage starts with: "void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);", so c is an int, isn't it?

Comment: "The value is passed as an int, but the function fills the block of memory using the unsigned char conversion of this value." https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm

Comment: Also, I think it's supposed to be `memcpy(ary, orig, size);` since `orig` is technically a pointer (or rather a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of bools).

Comment: You don't need to `malloc` this in the first place.

Comment: Re “The problem i see with this code is that it depends on a boolean taking 1 byte”: No, it does not. `sizeof(bool[4][3])` gives the number of bytes needed for an array of 4 arrays of 3 `bool`, regardless of whether `bool` is one byte or not. Supposing `bool` and `false` are as defined by `<stdbool.h>`, `false` in `memset(ary, false, size);` will be automatically promoted to the `int` value 0. `memset(ary, false, size);` sets the entire array to bytes of value zero, also regardless of the size of `bool`. Those bytes will represent the `_Bool` value 0, regardless of the size of `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the `[4]`, there's nothing wrong with your code. I would however recommend to use this:

```
bool (*ary)[3] = calloc(1, sizeof(bool[4][3]));
...
free(ary);
```

Done. Some notes:

- Note the `[3]`, not a 4. This is an array pointer pointing at `bool [3]` arrays. The reason why we use this over `bool (*ary)[4][3]` is because if we discard one dimension - which always has to be the left-most one - we can use the handy `arr[i][j]` syntax, which is much more readable than `(*ary)[i][j]`.
- Note that `calloc` will zero out the whole array as part of the allocation process. That's pretty much the only reason why `calloc` exists in the first place.
- If you need to init the array to something else than `false` then indeed use `malloc` + `memcpy`. But this will perhaps be a tiny bit slower than just one `calloc` call. Always prioritize code readability over micro-optimizations, however.

Comment: Oooook, so that's why my printf is returning a 1 where i expected a 0 ;-)

Comment: I'm actually marking your reply as correct, but may i ask: If i use calloc it seems to me i'm assuming false will map to 0... Should i rely on this?

Comment: `bool (*ary)[3] = calloc(4, sizeof *ary);` would be my preference here

Comment: ok, i see, the standard guarantees false always expands to zero and true to one

Comment: @roirodriguez Yes this is guaranteed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think that's less readable, but it's subjective coding style. That style does not scale well. `bool (*ary)[3][4] = calloc(2, sizeof *ary);` is IMO far less readable than `bool (*ary)[3][4] = calloc(1, sizeof (bool[2][3][4]));` See [How to properly use malloc?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285898/285910#answer-285910) for more arguments regarding why `sizeof *var` isn't some universal great trick.

Comment: I agree it's subjective and I agree with your article when the pointer comes from the outside. Otherwise, when defining the pointer, I almost always prefer `sizeof *ptr`. Sidenote: You have a typo in the article: _"However, it only allocates `1 * sizeof(int(*)[5])`. That is, 20 bytes, which is of course wrong."_ Should be `1 * sizeof(int[5])`.

Comment: @Lundin, what about `typeof(bool[2][3][4]) *arr = calloc(1, sizeof *arr)` ?

Comment: @tstanisl You get the wrong pointer type that way, `bool (*)[2][3][4]` instead of `bool(*)[3][4]` which is the convenient form.